# Crop not showing image and not working - android

Tags: android, crop

I am trying to crop in my Android tablet, but it's not working.

**I am using a Nexus 10.**

**Well... here is my code for cropping:**

```
private void doCrop(){
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
    intent.setDataAndType(mImageCaptureUri, "image/*");
    List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities( intent, 0 );
    int size = list.size();
    if (size == 0) {            
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can not find image crop app", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    } else {
        intent.setData(mImageCaptureUri);        
        intent.putExtra("outputX", 648);
        intent.putExtra("outputY", 486);
        intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
        intent.putExtra("scale", true);
        intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
        if (size == 1) {
            Intent i        = new Intent(intent);
            ResolveInfo res = list.get(0);
            i.setComponent( new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
            startActivityForResult(i, CROP_RESULT);
        } else {
        }

    }
}
```

**Here is my dialog to ask for "Camera" or "Gallery":**

```
private void startDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder myAlertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    myAlertDialog.setTitle("Selecione uma foto!");
    myAlertDialog.setMessage("Choose a source");

    myAlertDialog.setPositiveButton("Gallery", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            pictureActionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, null);
            pictureActionIntent.setType("image/*");
            pictureActionIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, GALLERY_PICTURE);
        }
    });

    myAlertDialog.setNegativeButton("Camera", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            pictureActionIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            storagePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/tmp/android.jpg";
            pictureActionIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, storagePath);
            startActivityForResult(pictureActionIntent, CAMERA_PICTURE);
        }
    });
    myAlertDialog.show();
}
```

**And here is my onActivityResult:**

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bmp;
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        switch (requestCode){
        case GALLERY_PICTURE :
            mImageCaptureUri = data.getData();
            doCrop();
        break;
        case CROP_RESULT :
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras != null) {               
                bmp = extras.getParcelable("data");
                bmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, 648, 486, true);
                Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmp);
                btnTitular.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, d, null, null);
            }
            File f = new File(mImageCaptureUri.getPath());            
            if (f.exists()) f.delete();
            Intent inten3 = new Intent(this, CadTitularActivity.class);
            startActivity(inten3);
        break;
        case CAMERA_PICTURE :
            doCrop();
        break;
        }
    }        
}
```

**Here is what is happening:**

When I grab an image from **gallery**, the crop is show but when I click in "ok" to crop the image, it does nothing.

When I grab a picture from the **camera**, it does nothing. It just shows "Loading picture" and nothing happens.

ANY IDEAS?

Remember: I am using a Nexus 10. I already heard that this cropping stuff doesn't work for all devices.

Any help is welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is the crop intent has to be set at 256 x 256 (or less) for the output x and y.

so change the code from this:

```
intent.putExtra("outputX", 648);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 486);
```

to this:

```
intent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
```

It should then work for you.